# How to add JavaScript event handler to dynamically generated TextBoxes on ASP control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, event-listener

We have conditions that will dynamically add TextBoxes to an ASP User Control like this:

```
if (conditionIsTrue) {
    TextBox textField = new TextBox();
    Panel.controls.Add(textField);
}
```

I would like to add an event listener that left-pads the TextBox value when the user unfocuses or is done editing the TextBox.

I have tried the following C# implementation but for some reason the values are not being handled by the listener.

```
if (conditionIsTrue) {
    TextBox textField = new TextBox();
    textField.TextChanged += new EventHandler(LeadingZero_Handler);
    Panel.controls.Add(textField)
}

public void LeadingZero_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int FieldLength = 10;
    if((TextBox)sender.Text.Length < FieldLength)
    {
        (TextBox)sender.Text = (TextBox).sender.Text.PadLeft(FieldLength,'0');
    }
}
```

Is there is a way that I could implement the event listener in JavaScript on the ASP Control, but add the JavaScript listener attribute during/when the TextBox is being dynamically generated in the C# code?

Comment: Add `textField.AutoPostBack = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the code behind.

```
textField.AutoPostBack = true;
```

But if all you do is add some zero padding, and you are doing nothing else in `LeadingZero_Handler`, I would recommend a front-end approach. That saves you a PostBack.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function LeadingZero(element) {
        var str = element.value;
        var padding = "0000000000";
        if (str.length < 10) {
            element.value = padding.substring(0, padding.length - str.length) + str;
        }
    }
</script>
```

And then add the script to the TextBox instead of the AutoPostBack and the TextChanged handler.

```
textField.Attributes.Add("onblur", "LeadingZero(this)");
```

Comment: I have tried this implementation and it seems that "onblur" doesn't work well with IE 11 or or there is something fundamentally wrong with this approach. However, it does seem that the method is being applied to my elements which is exactly what I was asking for.